# I want to use a for or while loop for the line genarting speed,

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Is there a way where I can make a loop of this in my code ?

```
}

  line(700,lineY + 90, 0, lineY + 90);
  lineY = lineY + speed
  if(lineY >= 370){
      
    lineY = 250


  }
```

As u can see in my Code its every time the same code but with a changing of 30

```
let lineY=250;
let speed=0.3;
var r;
var g;
var b;
var a;
var n;
var m;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(700, 500);
  rectMode(CORNER);
  frameRate(60);
  n = color(255,0,0);
  m = color(0,0,255);
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 0, 0);
  
  r = random(255); // r is a random number between 0 - 255
  g = random(255); // g is a random number betwen 100 - 200
  b = random(255); // b is a random number between 0 - 100
  a = random(200,255); // a is a random number between 200 - 255
  var t = map(mouseX,0,width,0,1.0);
  var c = lerpColor(n,m,t);

  strokeWeight(0); //Horizont Rechteck
  fill(41,0,33)
  rect(0, 0, 700, 250);


  fill(c)
  circle(350, 80, 250);

  fill(0) //Berg links
  triangle(125, 250, 275, 250, 200, 150);

  fill(0) //Berg Mitte
  triangle(225, 250, 475, 250, 350, 100);

  fill(0) // Berg rechts
  triangle(575, 250, 425, 250, 500, 125);

  strokeWeight(5);
  stroke(r,g,b);
  line(125,250, 200, 150);

  strokeWeight(5);
  stroke(r,g,b);
  line(425,250, 500, 125);

  strokeWeight(5);
  stroke(r,g,b);
  line(225,250, 350, 100);


  strokeWeight(3);  // Linie am Horizont
  stroke(0,204,204);
  line(700,250, 0, 250);

  strokeWeight(3); //mitte‚
  stroke(0,204,204);
  line(350,250, 350, 700);

  strokeWeight(3); //linksmitte
  stroke(0,204,204);
  line(250,250, 50, 700);

  strokeWeight(3); //links
  stroke(0,204,204);
  line(100,250, -100, 700);

  strokeWeight(3); //rechtsmitte
  stroke(0,204,204);
  line(450,250, 650, 700);

  strokeWeight(3); //rechts
  stroke(0,204,204);
  line(600,250, 800, 700);


  line(700,lineY , 0, lineY );
  lineY = lineY + speed
  if(lineY >= 280){
      
    lineY = 250


  }
  
  line(700,lineY + 30, 0, lineY + 30);
  lineY = lineY + speed
  if(lineY >= 310){
      
    lineY = 250


  }

  line(700,lineY + 60, 0, lineY + 60);
  lineY = lineY + speed
  if(lineY >= 340){
      
    lineY = 250


  }

  line(700,lineY + 90, 0, lineY + 90);
  lineY = lineY + speed
  if(lineY >= 370){
      
    lineY = 250


  }

  line(700,lineY + 120, 0, lineY + 120);
  lineY = lineY + speed
  if(lineY >= 400){
      
    lineY = 250


  }

  line(700,lineY + 150, 0, lineY + 150);
  lineY = lineY + speed
  if(lineY >= 430){
      
    lineY = 250


  }

  line(700,lineY + 180, 0, lineY + 180);
  lineY = lineY + speed
  if(lineY >= 460){
      
    lineY = 250


  }

  line(700,lineY + 210, 0, lineY + 210);
  lineY = lineY + speed
  if(lineY >= 490){
      
    lineY = 250


  }

}
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that summarizes the **specific problem**"_ + [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) :

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
  line(700, lineY + (i * 30), 0, lineY + (i * 30));
  lineY += speed; //equivalent to lineY = lineY + speed;
  if (lineY >= 280 + (i * 30)) {
    lineY = 250;
  }
}
```